# What are approaches to, accuracy and value of forecasting in/for highly volatile environments?

Tags: forecasting, predictive-models, volatility-forecasting

More details in my Quora question here: http://qr.ae/x4s5Z. Please note that this question is not about *value*, *approaches* and *methods* of *forecasting* in general, but specifically about forecasting in/for **highly volatile environments**, such as financial market and economy, in general. Moreover, I'm curious about sense and value of highly ambiguous (inaccurate) forecasts, as illustrated by the `TSLA` stock price forecast chart, presented in my question. I'm less interested in financial aspect of this, but much more in data science aspect, hence posting this question to the Cross Validated site. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Speaking about financial markets, there is a high value in inaccurate forecasts if they still positively correlate with the predicted value.  You can earn a lot of money on them.  For instance, the prediction of a stock price change in the next month, with correlation is as low as 0.2, is still valuable (if you can make such predictions for years).

For daily changes of dollar/euro futures and such, the correlation of 0.05 is great and useful.

It is very hard to obtain such predictions, because the stock price dynamics is close to random walking.

However, these predictions are valuable only for those who is able to make them.  They are not valuable after they are published, because the stock price already takes into account the prediction.

Anyone who claims that he is able to predict a stock price dynamics with the correlation of 1 or even 0.5 is either lies or uses some information not avaliable to others.

Comment: Thank you for your thoughts! I agree with your points and I certainly understand the value of forecasting in general. The point of my question (perhaps not perfectly emphasized) was the value of forecasting in highly volatile environment, which produces a symmetrical "trend range", as illustrated by the TSLA forecast. One of the people, who answered my question on Quora, had a good point: despite high inaccuracy / tolerance / error margin of such symmetrical forecasts, they still provide value for realizing limits of opportunity/risk in business scenarios, aiding in strategic decision making.